# MySQL group by + order by incomprehensibly slow

Tags: mysql, sql

I am not sure what is happening, but MySQL should handle this just fine in my opinion.

I have SQL like this.

```
SELECT u.id AS user_id, SUM(t.amount) AS total
FROM user u
INNER JOIN transaction t ON t.user_id = u.id
WHERE u.condition = true
GROUP BY u.id
ORDER BY total DESC;
```

This query runs for 10 seconds.

If I remove ORDER BY clause, the time is around 4 seconds.

Tables are very large but after GROUP BY I have only 40 rows. Does it really take 6 seconds to sort 40 rows? I would say this should be handled by the optimizer.

However if I run the query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT u.id AS user_id, SUM(t.amount) AS total
    FROM user u
    INNER JOIN transaction t ON t.user_id = u.id
    WHERE u.condition = true
    GROUP BY u.id
) data
ORDER BY total DESC;
```

This query runs for 4 seconds. I understand I forced MySQL to sort only the 40 records retrieved from inner select.

I really do not understand one thing. MySQL cannot sort by total before GROUP BY.. So what is slowing the query so much?

In this case I can use the second query, but if I had another inner SQL, MySQL would start creating temporary tables and it would kill the performance maybe more than ORDER BY. Another "problem" is that I use ORM and using raw SQL is really painful.

Thanks for suggestions.

EDIT:

Execution plan with ORDER BY

[image: Execution plan with ORDER BY]

Execution plan without ORDER BY

[image: Execution plan without ORDER BY]

I can see in execution plan, there is additional filesort + temporary when using ORDER BY..

Comment: I find this very curious -- unless you have a column named `total` in one of the tables that is confusing the `order by`.

Comment: I had a similar problem with Oracle. Adding the `order by` for some reason it executed a full table scan. Check your execution plan. Your solution with an inner query is really nice though.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I used this markup for readability. In fact, ORM is creating aliases on its own - in this case it is "sclr_13" and it really is not in any table :-). But good point which might be useful later :-).

Comment: @RobertKock . . . This is surprising because the `ORDER BY` is on a computed column.  It has to be calculated *after* the aggregation, so I cannot think of a way that the execution plans could really be different.  That is why I say it is surprising.

Comment: I was surprised as well. Compare the execution plans of the first query with and without the order by.

Comment: I have appended execution plans to my question. It really seems like MySQL is doing something really wrong.

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using? `SELECT VERSION()`

Comment: @RaymondNijland 10.3.13-MariaDB-1:10.3.13+maria~stretch-log

Comment: @RaymondNijland No warnings. The query with inner select is fine. The problem is only with the first query. I would say these two should be equivalent but they are not. 

Understand the second query with inner select as a workaround, not a problem nor a solution.

Comment: Yes never mind i now notice the second query runs faster then the first one  4 second vs 10 second i really should go and sleep i geuss.. Removing those comments.

Comment: @RaymondNijland nvm. 1:36 AM here :).

Comment: same over here.. one hint still adding a `ORDER BY NULL` in the inner sql might make it faster as it disables the defualt sorting off `GROUP BY`, atleast it does on MySQL, you can always try..

Comment: @RaymondNijland Hmm, it made the 2nd query as slow as the 1st.. It seems like the mariaDB sees ORDER BY and make some calculations without bothering to check by what I am ordering.. It didn´t help, but maybe pointed me to the right direction, thanks.

Comment: Just to be shure: There ist an index on user_id on table transaction? Which (other) indexes are on table transaction?

Comment: I think you have to check the indexes you have on these tables